# If a function is continuous and converges finitely, then it is bounded

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, proof-writing

Suppose that $f$ is a continuous function on $[a,+\infty)$ and that there exists a finite limit $\lim \limits_{x \to +\infty}⁡ f(x)$, then $f$ is bounded.

I know that from the assumption I can conclude that $f$ is uniformly continuous on that interval, but how can I use this to show that $f$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C := \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f(x)$. Then there is $b$ such that $|f(x)-C|<1$ for $x \ge b$. Now consider $f$ on $[a,b]$ and $[b,+\infty)$.

Comment: $|f(x)−C|<1$  , why $1$, I thought it should be $\epsilon$

Comment: $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, I chose $\epsilon:=1$.

Answer (score 1):

> **Definition.** $\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ f(x)=k\Longleftrightarrow  } \forall \epsilon >0\;, \exists K:x>K\Rightarrow \left| f(x)-k \right| <\epsilon$

Taking $\epsilon = 1$, we have

$\left| f(x)-k \right| < 1\Rightarrow -1+k<f(x)<1+k\;  \text{(This is the upper )} $
for all $x\in (K ,\infty )$.

Now take $M = \max\limits_{x\in[a,K]}f(x)$ (It exists because $f$ is continuous on a compact)

Finally, we take $H=\max { \left\{ M,k+1 \right\} } $ and we have $f(x)\le H\; \forall x\in [a,\infty)$

Comment: Why put me -1, I don't understand

Comment: Although I'm still trying to understand what you are doing but It wasn't me who gave you that -1

Comment: That's ok ... XD